# how to test robotium test project apk file

Tags: android, robotium

i am using robotium to create a test project. Suppose my app name is MyApp and test project name is MyAppTest.i am giving both MyApp.apk and MyAppTest.apk to a QA tester (not giving the source code of app and test project). As per my knowledge tester can run the testcase using these two apks with the help of command prompt.but i need to know whether there is any other tools or anything like that to run the testcases only with these two apks.please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Robotium with an apk and without the source code, the apk has to be unsigned and signed with the keystore of the user who would be testing it. 
This link on Robotium's wiki explains about testing apks without source : http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles

re-sign.jar provides an easy drag & drop way to unsign the apk: http://www.troido.de/en/downloadslsmallgsoftware-a-driverslsmallg

For signing an unsigned apk refer to this blogpost :
http://dimitar.me/how-to-sign-an-unsigned-android-package-apk-file/

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this helps you ,

1. Install both MyApp & MyAppTest apk in the emulator
2. Goto,Dev Tools -> Instrumentation -> (select your package name)
   The test project will start run.

if u wany do same in the device install developer tools APK.( i haven't tried that..)

Answer (score 0):

Detailed instructions are here :

https://robotium.googlecode.com/files/AndroidCalculatorAPKTest.pdf